# How to create a drop shadow effect for the button in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Code that creates drop shadow for the element:

```
var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this.btn).Compositor;
var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
spriteVisual.Size = new Vector2((float)btn.ActualWidth, (float)btn.ActualHeight);
var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
dropShadow.Color = Colors.Orange;
spriteVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this.btn, spriteVisual);
```

But shadow overlaps button. How to make shadow not to overlap button?
[image: Button]

Comment: The issue is caused by your call to [SetElementChildVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.setelementchildvisual). As documented, *"[t]he Visual is added as the last child, therefore **on top of the rest of the element in z-order**."* You have to make sure that your drop shadow is below the button visual in z-order.

Comment: I try insert spriteVisual at bottom. compositor.CreateContainerVisual().Children.InsertAtBottom(spriteVisual); But the shadow still overlaps button.

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41283323/1172352 points to an open source library that would let you do this declaratively in XAML markup, if you'd prefer that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Either you create brush for your **spriteVisual**

```
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Button).Compositor;
    var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    spriteVisual.Size = new Vector2((float)Button.ActualWidth, (float)Button.ActualHeight);
    var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
    dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
    dropShadow.Color = Colors.Orange;
    var colorBrush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    spriteVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;
    spriteVisual.Brush = colorBrush;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Button, spriteVisual);
```

Or create XAML container for your spriteVisual before **Button** and **SetElementChildVisual** into **Shadow** canvas

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Shadow"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button" Width="300" Height="100" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```