# Uwp more deep shadow effect for text or textblock

Tags: c#

I am trying to make more deep black shadow effect to make readable text , infront white background .

I am using this code

c# void method of loaded

```
var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this.grid).Compositor;
var brush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.Black);
var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
spriteVisual.Size = this.grid.RenderSize.ToVector2();

var dropshadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
dropshadow.Mask = txtBlock.GetAlphaMask();
dropshadow.Color = brush.Color;
dropshadow.BlurRadius = 9.5f;
dropshadow.Opacity = 1.9f;
spriteVisual.Shadow = dropshadow;
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this.grid, spriteVisual);
```

xaml

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid Loaded="grid_Loaded"
                      x:Name="grid" />

        <TextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"
                    x:Name="txtBlock"
                    Text="Drop Shadow"
                    Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>

   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Result
[![Result image][1]][1]

My Problem it is not enough black color shadow effect or opacity to watch the text .
Result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/riri5.png
I am trying to make that black effect more deep,

My Target to make shadow effect like this
Target
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ETu1.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283323/2884831

Comment: Hope this help!