# Make text more visible on blur image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

This is how I make Blur:

```
await BlurBackround.Blur(value: 7, duration: 10, delay: 0).StartAsync();
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Problem is on white elements of image. It is any way to make image more darker before blur or make text letters black border?

Comment: Actually, although UWP toolkit doesn't support it yet, the underlying Composition API does give us a blend effect mode where you can add an additional *tint* color on top of your blur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common pattern to ensure text visible over the image, is to apply a solid black color layer with 0.2-0.3 Opacity between the text and image components.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a drop shadow..? It helps to add some contrast between the text and the background. This post shows how to do it in xaml -> [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282958/drop-shadow-effect-in-universal-windows-application)

Comment: Keep in mind that adding a drop-shadow (or any other effect) directly to a control will usually make and child content (like text) slightly blurry.  The usual solution it to apply the effect to a copy of the real object, ordered behind the real object.  You will have to experiment with different options to find the right balance.